# Returning the result of comparing two strings using 'contains'

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

So, I've got two strings being input and the subString looked for in the mString. When I change the method to boolean it returns the correct output of true or false (by using return on the contains statement).

I don't know how to use that statement to check the outcome of that contains operator. I've got the following done up.

```
public class CheckingString
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // adding boolean value to indicate false or true
        boolean check;

        // scanner set up and input of two Strings (mString and subString)
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is the long string you want to enter? ");
        String mString = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the short string that will be looked for in the long string? ");
        String subString = scan.nextLine();

        // using the 'contain' operator to move check to false or positive.
        // used toLowerCase to remove false negatives
        check = mString.toLowerCase().contains(subString.toLowerCase());

        // if statement to reveal resutls to user
        if (check = true)
        {
            System.out.println(subString + " is in " + mString);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No, " + subString + " is not in " + mString);
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a way to make that check field work properly to return a value in the if-else statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (check = true){
```

should be:

```
if (check == true){
```

Normally you would write:

```
if(check)
```

to check for true

and:

```
if(!(check))
```

or:

> if(!check)

to check for false.

Comment: Doh... I can't believe I missed that. Good to know on the boolean if-statmenet too.

Comment: Common enough that I spotted it right away :-) (a lot of students do it).  Only happens with booleans at least.

Answer (score 5):

the trivial mistake:

change `if(check = true)` to `if(check == true)` or just `if (check)`

by doing `check = true` you are assigning true to check so the condition `if(check = true)` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to use a boolean variable in an if statement is

```
if (check)
```

Note that you don't need to use an equality operator, which avoids the error which you made.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 if (check) {
        System.out.println(subString + " is in " + mString);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No, " + subString + " is not in " + mString);
    }
```